# get_the_date call not populating within loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I have a recent posts loop in my news template that is pulling everything but the date for some reason.

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
            'numberposts' => 15,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ));
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($recent_posts as $post) : ?>
                <div class="news-item-block col-md-4" role="article">
                    <a class="news-item-image-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post['ID']) ?>">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post['ID'], 'news-grid-image'); ?>
                    </a>
                    <span class="news-item-date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'M d, Y' ); ?></span>
                    <a class="news-item-title" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post['ID']) ?>">
                        <h1><?php echo $post['post_title'] ?></h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
        </div>
```

Can't seem to figure out the problem. Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using foreach loop, you need to pass post id to get date of that post. replace below line:

`<span class="news-item-date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'M d, Y' ); ?></span>`

with this:

`<span class="news-item-date"><?php echo get_the_date('M d, Y', $post['ID']); ?></span>`

and you will get perfect date of your post